# problems of creating object instances in python

Tags: python, class, object

I want to define a class and create an object instance. But always get error. 
The code goes like this:

```
class complex:
    def _init_(self,realpart,imagpart):
        self.r=realpart
        self.i=imagpart

x=complex(3,4)
```

the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "pyshell#5", line 1, in "module" <br>
  x=complex(3,4) <br>
  TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

so what is the problem?

thanks for your reading!

Comment: it should be `__init__` not `_init_`

Comment: Python has native support for complex numbers. `3+4j` for example

Answer (score 2):

`_init_` should have two underscores on each side:

```
>>> class complex:
...     def __init__(self,realpart,imagpart):
...         self.r=realpart
...         self.i=imagpart
... 
>>> x=complex(3,4)
```

Also, just so you know, Python already has a `complex` type:

```
>>> 2+3j
(2+3j)
>>> complex(2, 3)
(2+3j)
```

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` supposed to have 2 underscores surrounding it rather than 1

So

```
def _init_(self,realpart,imagpart):
```

should be

```
def __init__(self,realpart,imagpart):
```

- One more suggesting, instead of multiple assignments, tuple unpacking would be more readable and marginally efficient
- Prefer new Type Class construct, which derives from `object`
- [PEP8 suggests](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) to use CamelCase for Class Names
- Always use the batteries if available instead of rolling your own. Python already supports complex types by default

SO here it goes

```
class complex(object):
    def __init__(self,realpart,imagpart):
        self.r, self.i=realpart, imagpart
```